# Basic information of angular promisses

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am unable to understand, What is promise in angular?

Can any one tell me what is promises in angularjs. Why you are using these promises. Before these promises how can we handle asynchronous calls. Can you tell me detailed.

Comment: A simple article [Promises in AngularJS, Explained as a Cartoon](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an analogy:

Every Sunday morning, a father asks his son to go and find out the weather forecast for the afternoon, by using his super-strong telescope to look across the horizon from the tallest hill by their house. The son promises his dad he will go and get the weather forecast. He creates a promise with his dad at the door when he leaves.

At that point, the dad decides if the weather tomorrow is good, he'll prepare a fishing trip for tomorrow. If it's bad he won't. Also, if the son is unable to get a forecast, he'll stay in as well.

[This link](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) also helps promises.